# SSRS Email subscription delivery extension error

Tags: reporting-services

While everything has been configured and working off SSRS2012 in native mode, we have been facing an issue with a sporadic event with email subscriptions where I have exhausted all known troubleshooting steps.

The email subscriptions would fail 3 out of 10 times with a weird error

> The delivery extension for this subscription could not be loaded.

Sometimes the email subscriptions would work flawless and the next run would pop this error.

- The remote SMTP server that is used for other SSRS environments has been used for this environment as well.
- I have gone through the reportserverconfig file and matched it with other deployments and do not find any glaring differences which might result this sporadic behaviour.
- I have tried commenting out the Report Server Document library delivery extension code as well, but that hasn't helped either.
- SSRS logs do not provide any pointers as to what might be the issue.

Any ideas as to what else can be checked to get any leads on this issue?

Comment: Is this a scale out deployment?

Comment: Yes, it is a scale out deployment consisting of two servers. Both the servers have the same smtp configuration.

Comment: You said you checked the logs. Is the email subscription failing always for the same server?

Comment: Both the servers are behind a load balancer, We would receive reports off the email subscriptions from either of these two servers, and quite surprisingly this failure message would originate randomly on either of these two servers. This is basically what is bothering me about this abnormal behavior

Comment: Sebastien, Finally, got this issue resolved by reworking the entire mailing configuration on both the servers. Not sure what went amiss in the previous configuration, but now things are working as expected. Thanks for looking into this issue.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know and glad you resolved your issue.